# How to automatically fill-in model fields in Django rest_framework serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let's assume I have a model like this:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField()
    b = models.CharField()
    c = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to setup a serializer in such a way that it automatically fills in field `c` and it is not required for a POST. I tried to overwrite the `create` function of the serializer, but it doesn't work:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('a', 'b')

    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
        Data.objects.c = 5
        return Data.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

However, if I try this, I end up with an `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: model_data.c`. What is the syntax that I have to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `Data.objects.c = 5` does nothing.

If you want to set this value yourself use `validated_data['c'] = 5` or `Data.objects.create(c=5, **validated_data)` (just not both at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Updated formatting.

The reason you're getting the error because field c is not set to `null = True` - as such an error is raised at the validation stage even before the serializer hits the create method.

Bear in mind that the process goes like this:

1. Submit serializer data
2. field-level validation happens - this includes checks for null integrity, min/max length etc and also any custom field validations defined in `def validate_<field_name>`
3. object-level validation happens - this calls the `def validate` method
4. validated data is passed to the save method, depending on how you designed the serializer - it will save the instance, or route the data to either `create` or `update`

All of the info regarding this can be found in Django's and DRF's docs.

A few things to consider:

- are you setting a global default for that field? If so, set the default in your models - `c = models.IntegerField(default=a_number_or_a_callable_that_returns_an_integer)`
- do you intend to display the field? If so, include `c` in your fields and add one more Meta attribute - `read_only_fields = ('c',)`
- If it's neither of the above, you might want to override the `validate_c` method

Apologies for the poor formatting, typing it on my phone - will update once I get to a computer

Comment: Please refrain from answering if you didn't understand the question, had to google the error message and post whatever you found as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Guess we all have to start somewhere. Though I'd appreciate if you didn't assume that I put an answer from Googling, because that wasn't what happened. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for the offensive assumption. I don't want to discourage you from attempting to help others, but, please, put a little more effort into researching the question and making sure your solution is applicable. One good quality answer is much better that five maybe-it-will-help answers.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! Your answer actually helped me to find another related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this in the serializer, there are hooks in the generic views that allow you to pass values to the serializer. So in your case you might have:

```
class DataViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(c=5)
```

See the "Save and deletion hooks" section [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#api-reference)